# Do I have the latest version of an OutSystems forge component?

Tags: outsystems

I have been struggling to determine whether I have the latest version of the [Google Maps](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/Component_Versions.aspx?ProjectId=680) component installed in my cloud environment. Checked in service center and in Service Studio but haven't found any version indicators.

Can anyone help me out on how to determine the version that I have installed currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to open the OutSystems tab and log in Forge. Then, just search for the Google Maps component. After that, click in the Versions tab and browse through the versions until you find the one marked with "Installed".

It should look something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It indeed does show the version you have installed, unless you have made customisations, then the installed version is not indicated

Answer (score 2):

If you connect to the OutSystems forge (using the leftmost black tab in Service Studio), search for the component and go into its page, if the button on the bottom right suggests that you "install", it means you are NOT running the latest version.

Other than that, there's currently no way to know the original version (as it appears in forge) of community components installed on your machine, unless the developers brand them explicitly (like the System components).

Comment: It indeed does show the version you have installed, unless you have made customisations, then the installed version is not indicated